# Error: Invariant violation: tried to get frame for out of range index NaN in react-native-ios and fetch-api

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dutS.png)Trying to display a blog content in react-native using fetch-api. I am much confused with the syntax as it is becoming complex with related examples I am getting online. The API was locally generated from PHP-PDO/MySQL and I have a url tested on POSTMAN. However, I receive error each time I am trying to display the content using fetch-api and console.log().

I have tried to check online for similar problem but it seems ambiguous as problems are different from mine. At a point I thought because I was using map() in my render, so I changed to FlatList.

ERROR:

```
This error is located at:
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:625)
    in FlatList (at Category.js:32)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Category.js:31)
    in Category (at App.js:10)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:9)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 
{ Text, 
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';


export default class Category extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }
        componentWillMount() {
           const that = this;
            fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await  fetch("http://localhost/rest_api_myblog/api/post/read.php");
            const json = await response.json();
            that.setState({ data: json});
            console.log(json);
          }

          }


          render() {
             return(
               <View style={styles.container}>
                 <FlatList 
                 data={this.state.data}
                 keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
                 renderItem={({ item }) =>
                 <Text>
                   {`${item.author} ${item.category_name}`}
                 </Text>}
                 />
               </View>
             );

          }
}
```

I want to display post contents

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the full error message that you are getting? I would also suggest that you paste the expected response from the api

Comment: Your error is probably caused by the fact that you are passing an object instead of an array to your FlatList. Change your state to `this.state = { data: [] }` you will also want to check that the json you receive is an array.

Comment: I did change it from this.state = { data: [ ]} to this.state = { data: {} } because of the error. The console.log() is not displaying anything. Even if I use response.ok. I have edited the code with full error

Comment: Remove the `setState` from your `componentWillMount`

Comment: the same thing...when I removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adjusted your code using axios. Try to see if you get along using axios but you need to add axios to project using npm i axios --save or yarn add axios then you can import it. 
What have done will give you a clue on how to go about the result.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    ScrollView, 
    StyleSheet,
    View, 
    Text
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Post extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(`http://localhost/rest_api_myblog/api/post/read.php`) //I used backtick 
        //.then(json => console.log(json.data.data[0].id)) //try to traverse to your json element by doing console.log to ensure you have a feedback
        .then(json => json.data.data.map(mydata =>(
            {
                author: `${mydata.author} ${mydata.id}`,
                id: mydata.registered 
            }
        )))
        //.then(newData => console.log(newData)) //also I did a console.log to check if the newData is working. 
        .then(newData => this.setState({posts: newData}))
        .catch(error => alert(error))

        }
    render(){
        return (
        <ScrollView>
             {   
                 this.state.posts.map((post, index) =>(
                     <Text key={index}>
                         {post.author}
                     </Text>
                 ))
             }
        </ScrollView>);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much, u have really saved the day with your explanations. Very explicit

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same error because I was trying to execute object not array. make sure you are using FlatList  an array